# How to change the name of the values on the x-axis

Tags: matlab

I'm reading out columns from many txt-files and ploting column 2 against column 9, as in my code here.

```
    x= str2num(tmp{2});
    y= str2num(tmp{9});
    scatter(x, y)
```

column 2 is constant for each txt file and in column one the numbers have a name, ex:

```
txt-file 1:        txt-file 2:
JM 100 0.9        KG 200 1.0
JM 100 0.7        KG 200 0.7
JM 100 0.6        KG 200 0.3
```

So, my question is. How can I get the values on the x-axis (100, 200 ect.) to be JM and KG instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ploting the data:

```
set (gca,'xtick',[100,200]):
set (gca, 'xticklabels', {'JM';'KG'});
```

If you have more, you can add as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the tags (JM and KG) from each file you can put them in a matrix:

```
tags = ['JM';'KG'];
```

Then you can set the labels with these tags

```
set(gca, 'xticklabel', tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in each of scatters you plot all the points in the same x value, so you have to first set the tick value to be only the one you want.

In Matlab 2014b and later, you can get the handle to the object and change it directly:

```
h = scatter(x, y);
h.Parent.XTick = x(1);
h.Parent.XTickLabel = tmp{1}(1);
```